# npm run watch - Exclude file

Tags: laravel, npm

As part of my build script using Laravel Mix, I'm needing to make a modification to one of the files inside the `resources/assets/sass` directory. The problem is that running `npm run watch` will then modify this file and the watcher re-runs the build process, causing an infinite recursive loop.

Is there any way to exclude an individual file from being watched for changes?

---

For example:

**webpack.mix.js**

```
// Do something with `resources/assets/sass/_modules.scss` first, then continue
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss');
```

**app.scss**

```
@include "_modules.scss";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with webpack not automatically updating your relative stylesheet URL's, try this:

In **webpack.mix.js**, add the following option:

```
processCssUrls: false
```

Source: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/options.md